# get_instance() function in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started migrating some projcts in CI2 to CI3.

The main problem is in core extensions, get_instance() always returns NULL

Just for any file ex: **/application/core/MY_Exceptions.php**

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions 
{
    private $_ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_ci = &get_instance();        

        var_dump($this->_ci);
    }
}
```

I always gets NULL return.

What am I doing wrong?

echo 'Thanks';

Comment: Exceptions are loaded before definition of get_instance. There is no logic Exception class/function to be loaded after the load of the system, as the system can break a part and there wont be any exceptions registered